# Gulp does not work after node-modules update

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, yarnpkg

Currently I use Gulp with tasks loaded through a chain of TS imports starting in gulpfile.ts

When I update some dependencies to the latest versions - gulp just stop to work. First I though that something wrong with the project itself, but then I found out that gulp cli is messed up in general - it does not recognize cli options. Most probably this is because I am using yargs in my project, and it may conflict somehow with gulp - but I dunno where to start looking from.

```
PS C:\ci> gulp gulp -T
[11:18:21] Tasks for C:\ci\gulpfile.js
...


PS C:\ci> yarn add build-process@2.1.5-alpha.4
yarn add v1.17.3
warning package.json: No license field
warning No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
warning No license field
warning "build-process" is already in "devDependencies". Please remove existing entry first before adding it to "dependencies".
success Saved 8 new dependencies.
info Direct dependencies
└─ build-process@2.1.5-alpha.4
info All dependencies
├─ @kwsites/file-exists@1.1.1
├─ @kwsites/promise-deferred@1.1.1
├─ @types/xml2js@0.4.5
├─ build-process@2.1.5-alpha.4
├─ disme-client@2.0.0
├─ fortify-client@2.0.0
├─ simple-git@2.20.1
└─ yargs@15.4.1
Done in 10.24s.
PS C:\ci> gulp gulp -T
error: unknown option '-T'
```

Comment: Try deleting the node_module folder and npm install it afresh!

Comment: did not work unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was case specific. One of the dependencies I have added had commander imported from index.js, which tried to parse gulp parameters on the initial loading. So the error itself 'error: unknow option -T' was not even from gulp.